# cocos2d frame rate lag on dictionary creation and search

Tags: objective-c, ios, search, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a create a simple iPhone game that would throughout the course of running be doing multiple checks to see if user input was a real word.  I have a 1.7mb text file (is this a reasonable size?) with each word on its own line containing all of the words in the english language.  This is the code that runs in the init method of the game scene.  `correctWords` is an array that will contain all of the users verified word guesses.  This code parses through the text file and puts all of the words into an array called `currentDict`:

```
    correctWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //set where to get the dictionary from
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"dictionary"] ofType:@"txt"];

    //pull the content from the file into memory
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    //convert the bytes from the file into a string
    NSString* string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                                 length:[data length] 
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    //split the string around newline characters to create an array
    NSString* delimiter = @"\n";
    currentDict = [string componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter];

    [currentDict retain];
```

and then to verify if the word the user inputs is in fact a word I have this check

```
if([currentDict containsObject: userInput]){
```

Whenever the game scene loads, there is a very noticeable delay (3-4 seconds) on the device itself, although there it happens almost instantly in the simulator, and then also I have animations running throughout most of the game, but whenever it tries to verify a word, there is a slight but noticeable lag in the animations.  I am just wondering if there is a better way to get the dictionary loaded into memory, or if there is some kind of standard practice for verifying words.  Also why would checking if it is a word cause a lag in the animation? I  had assumed the animation was part of its own thread (and thus would theoretically not be affected)

Comment: 1.7 MB text equals tens of thousands, if not hundreds of thousands of words. Searching for a string in that dictionary *is* going to be slow. Of course the Simulator runs faster because it can utilize your Mac's CPU which is ten to hundred times faster than the iOS CPUs.

Comment: its around 70,000 words.  This size is somewhat unavoidable, but there are many games that use the same dictionary and have an effective method of loading it in.   I currently have it loaded into an array, but I am wondering if there is some sort of standard practice I can do for this?  Right now the search is just doing a o(n) search through all of the elements so that can be sped up to logn once I implement a binary search, but as far as loading it in, is an array the best option? should I be using a nsdictionary? what is the difference in terms of speed

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an alternative approach. I don't know how your game works, but it might make sense to give the player a limited set of possible word choices, for example something like Draw Something where there are only so many words you could type; then you would test against far fewer. Before the scene loads, you can have the set of possible words selected from your dictionary then provide letters or options (whatever your game is going) that only allows the user to come up with words that are in that set. Then you can test against a small set.

Another option is to repeat what I've said above frequently throughout your level, so the amount of available words are constantly changing, but load that set periodically when you're not in the middle of an animation or whatever. If there is a brief pause in the game play as the level gets harder, then load new words, or something similar.

That way the real-time game play is not affected by a large dictionary but you can still offer many options throughout the gameplay.

Comment: the game will need to have the ability to check the validity of words, otherwise it will lose most of its functionality.  I have implemented a binary search for the dictionary so it runs super fast now.  I also moved the loading of the dictionary to the appDelegate so it only needs to load once.  That still takes about 4 seconds... Should I be pushing for it to go much faster than that? or should I just accept that it wont really run faster than that

Comment: there are plenty of games and apps that take more than 4 seconds to load so i wouldn't worry about that

Answer (score -3):

Nothing surprising that comparing thousands of string takes some time and causes lag in animation. You should something read about binary search, hashing, etc. Also loading entire file into NSString and then splitting it is very slow. Your code is just awful, sorry.

Comment: no need to insult the man. we're all learning, some of us are closer to the beginning of the curve than others. we learn from our mistakes, and the OP is learning too.